# Using HTTP2 with GKE and Google Managed Certificates

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I am using an Ingress using Google-managed SSL certs mostly similar to what is described here:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#setting_up_a_google-managed_certificate

However my backend service is a grpc service that is using HTTP2. According to the same documentation if I am using HTTP2 my backend needs to be ["configured with SSL".](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-http2#creating_the_deployment)

This sounds like I need a separate set of certificates for my backend service to configure it with SSL.

Is there a way to use the same Google managed certs here as well?

What are my other options here? I am using, Google managed certs for the Ingress not to manage any certs on my own, if I then use self signed certificates for my service, that kind of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Managed Certificates can only be used for the frontend portion of the load balancer (aka client to LB). If you need encryption from the LB to the backends you will have use self-signed certificates or some other way to store said certificates on GKE as secrets and configuring the Ingress to connect to the backend using these secrets.

Like this https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-xlb#setting_up_https_tls_between_client_and_load_balancer

Comment: yup that's what I ended up doing, but one confusing part of this was that the client doesnt need to know about the certificate used in the service at all.. This means lb -> backend communication happens with any certificate as long as it is TLS.

Comment: lb - backend communication is transparant to clients. The kind of loadbalancers generated with Ingress are L7 HTTP(s) proxies. Which means traffic from the client is terminated at the lb level using the external cert (the one you provisioned using managed certs) and a new connection is established form the lb to the backend encrypted by what ever cert is presented by the backend. In other terms the lb - backend is handleded kind of a client - lb way but internal

Answer (score 2):

i don't think it's required to create SSL for the backend services if you are terminating the HTTPS at **LB** level. You can attach your certs to at LB level and the backed-end will be HTTPS > HTTP.

You might need to create **SSL/TLS** new cert in case there is diff version `ssl-protocols: TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3`, Cipher set in your ingress controller configmap which you are using **Nginx ingress controller**, **Kong** etc.

If you are looking for End to End **HTTPS** traffic definitely you **need to create a cert** for the **backend service**.

You can also create/manage the **Managed certificate** or **Custom cert** with [Cert manager](https://cert-manager.io/) the **K8s secret** and **mount** to deployment which will be used further by the **service**, in that case, no need to manage or create the certs. Ingress will **passthrough** the HTTPS request to service directly.

In this case, it will be an end-to-end **HTTPS** setup.

**Update** :

> Note: To ensure the load balancer can make a correct HTTP2 request to
> your backend, your backend must be configured with SSL. For more
> information on what types of certificates are accepted, see Encryption
> from the load balancer to the backends ." end to end tls seems to be a
> requirement for HTTP2

This is my site https://findmeip.com it's running on **HTTP2** and terminating the **SSL/TLS** at the Nginx level only.

Definitely, it's good to go with the suggested practice so you can use the **ESP** option from the Google, setting GKE ingress + ESP + grpc stack.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-proxy-startup-options?hl=tr

If not want to use **ESP** check above suggested :

> You can Mount Managed certificate to
> deployment which will be used further by the service, in that case, no
> need to manage or create the certs. In other words, cert-manager will create/manage/re-new SSL/TLS on behalf of you in K8s secret which will used by service.

Comment: looking the note linked above; 

"Note: To ensure the load balancer can make a correct HTTP2 request to your backend, your backend must be configured with SSL. For more information on what types of certificates are accepted, see Encryption from the load balancer to the backends ."

end to end tls seems to be a requirement for HTTP2

Comment: as said not necessary but you can follow the process if want and do e2e setup also, however i shared and discussed all the possible ways you can follow. With self sign cert cert-manager and etc.

Comment: idea is to terminate the client at LB level as suggested in first line what boredabdel said. use cert-manager to create cert for LB and manage it at ingress and that's it unless you require END to END cert.